# Issue using strcmp function in an If Else statement

Tags: c

So I am currently working on a project at university and I want to use the strcmp function to check a user's input. However I am running into an issue where if I input an incorrect string that is greater than what it is checking for, it breaks in the sense that if I were to input the correct string afterward, it does not recognise it and says it is incorrect again.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

char function[13];
char result[13];

void toLower() 
{  
   
    for (int i = 0; function[i] != '\0'; i++) 
    {
        result[i] = tolower(function[i]);
    }

}

char FunctionChoice()
{
    printf("And another one\n");
    do
    {
        printf("Enter a 4, 5, 13, or 15 character word\n");
        scanf("%s", function);
        toLower();
        if (strcmp(result, "circumference") == 0)
        {
            printf("A");
            break;
        }
        else if (strcmp(result, "area") == 0)
        {
            printf("B");
            break;
        }
        
        printf("Please check your spelling and re-enter\n");
        
    }
    while ((!(strcmp(result, "circumference") == 0)) || (!(strcmp(result, "area") == 0)));
}

int main()
{
    printf("There's your print statement\n");
    FunctionChoice();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure what the issue is, probably because I don't know the in-depth of how the function works. I don't think it is caused by the toLower function but writing this I should probably test that too.

Comment: `char function[13];` has enough space for a 12-character word (plus null terminator), yet you are asking the user to input up to 15? That cannot work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strcmp` looks for a `\0` byte. Your `toLower` function doesn't put it at the end of `result`, so when you input `"zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"` and then `"circumference"`, then `result == "circumferencezz"`. It can be easily fixed by setting every byte of `result` array to 0 (using `memset`) or just putting 0 after the last byte of the string.

Other mistakes:

- Your arrays were too small to fit 15 characters. You need 16 bytes (15 + 1 for `\0`)
- It's not C++, function that takes no arguments should have `void` inside argument list.
- Use unsigned types for iterating over arrays. `size_t` is the best for that
- I've simplified your while loop condition to use `x != y` instead of `!(x == y)`
- EDIT: Set a bound on the length of the buffer to avoid buffer overflow. You can do that with `scanf("%15s", function)` - it means that at most 15 characters will be read from the standard input into `function`.

Fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

char function[16];
char result[16];

void toLower(void) 
{  
    memset(result, 0, sizeof(result));
    for (size_t i = 0; function[i] != '\0'; i++) 
    {
        result[i] = tolower(function[i]);
    }
}

char FunctionChoice(void)
{
    printf("And another one\n");
    do
    {
        printf("Enter a 4, 5, 13, or 15 character word\n");
        scanf("%15s", function);
        toLower();
        if (strcmp(result, "circumference") == 0)
        {
            printf("A");
            break;
        }
        else if (strcmp(result, "area") == 0)
        {
            printf("B");
            break;
        }
        
        printf("Please check your spelling and re-enter\n");
        
    }
    while ((strcmp(result, "circumference") != 0) || (strcmp(result, "area") != 0));
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("There's your print statement\n");
    FunctionChoice();
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Changed format string in `scanf` to `"%15s"` to avoid buffer overflow.

Comment: It would be a good idea to prevent buffer overflow using `”%15s”` in the `scanf()` format.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler , I've just included your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've only been doing C for a few weeks so some of the I don't know the full scope of the language (doesn't help it's also my first time coding). I appreciate the effort and will try to understand what is doing what so that I know what I'm using :)

Comment: @Will If you appreciate the effort and think that I've answered your question, then please mark it as accepted. It really helps :)
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers